# Map with multiple arguments an Trees

Tags: haskell, tree

i have a problem with a map function and recursion.

I have a Tree data structure like this:

```
data Tree a = T a [Tree a] deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

I already have a working function to count "through" the Tree which works.

```
count :: Tree a -> Int
count (T _ xs) = 1 + sum(map count xs)
```

No i want a function to proof every element of the tree with a predicate

```
filterKnoten :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> [a]
filterKnoten p (T x []) = (if p(x) then [x] else []) 
filterKnoten p (T x xs) 
                    | p(x) == True = x:(map multP xs)
                    | p(x) == False = map multP xs
                    where multP = filterKnoten p
```

Some sample date would be

```
ex1 = T True [T False [T True[]] , T True []]
```

No when i call the method with for example

```
filterKnoten (==True) ex1
```

As a result I want to have list with all elements which fits my predicate, but the compile gives me this when i want to load the module

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for filterKnoten :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> [a]
      at WS11.hs:138:17
Expected type: Tree a -> a
  Actual type: Tree a -> [a]
In the first argument of `map', namely `multP'
In the expression: map multP xs
In an equation for `filterKnoten':
    filterKnoten p (T x xs)
      | p (x) == True = x : (map multP xs)
      | p (x) == False = map multP xs
      where
          multP = filterKnoten p
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So my question, why does map works with count and not with filterKnoten?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your major problem is that you're mapping a function of type `T a -> [a]` which gives you back `[[a]]` instead of the `[a]` you want. This can be fixed by changing `map` to `concatMap` from `Data.List`

```
import Data.List
...
filterKnoten :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> [a]
filterKnoten p (T x []) = if p x then [x] else []
filterKnoten p (T x xs) 
                    | p x       = x:(concatMap multP xs)
                    | otherwise = concatMap multP xs
                    where multP = filterKnoten p
```

Notice that I've also gotten rid of the useless `==True` and `==False`'s. `x == True` is precisely the same as `x` and when we're talking about to cases there's no point in computing the same thing twice. Especially since it's potentially very expensive. `otherwise` is just a synonym for `True` that prelude provides. I've also gotten rid of some of the unnecessary parens.

Finally, you can just dump the entire first case since `map` and `concatMap` work on empty lists.

Answer (score 5):

I imagine that writing the function using recursion is a useful exercise, but from a practical standpoint, you can just derive all of these functions with GHC extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}

import Data.Foldable    
import Data.Traversable 

data Tree a = T a [Tree a] deriving (Eq,Ord,Show, Functor, Traversable, Foldable)

filterTree :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> [a]
filterTree f = filter f . toList  -- toList is defined in Foldable
```

You don't need `Traversable` for this example, it is just one of the other useful things you can derive.

Comment: A better exercise is probably to implement the `Functor`, `Foldable` and `Traversable` instances by hand...